# How to move files from local git hub repository to another git repository

Tags: git, github

The issue is that every time I try to move the folders manually from my old repository to my new one, it gives me the error that there are too many folders to move for one folder.

I was told that if I can delete the last 3 or 4 folders from this string of folders, I should be able to move it and do an `npm install` and a few other steps to then push it to the new repository branch. I then tried that, but another few folders were giving the same issues in all different locations. So I figured there must be a way using git/github to move all those files from my old repository to the new one.

Unfortunately when I had the new repository set up, my access to the old one was revoked remotely so now I just have the local files of the old repository to move.

GitHub Desktop won't let me clone my old files over because the new repository exists (it makes no sense, but it says that word for word).

Is there a string of commands I can type in cmd where I can transfer all the files from Repository 1 to Repository 2 and then push the new Repository 2?

When I manually copy and paste the old repository files into the new one, it gives me this error for a few different folders.

> The source path is too long

I just need to know if i can move my files from my first repository to the second one using Git. Without using github.com or the Github Desktop app.

Comment: When I manually copy and paste the old repository files into the new one, it gives me "The source path is too long" error for like 3 different folders. I just need to know if i can move my files from my first repository to the second one using git. Without using github.com or the github desktop.

Answer (score 3):

First, realize that with Git, *every copy of the repository is a complete copy*. There are exceptions to this, shallow clones for instance... but most of the time that is not the case, and you have a full copy of the entire history already.

Second, you can have multiple remote URLs in a repo. Also, you can change the URL you're pointing to, if you no longer plan to use the prior URL.

You don't need to do any of this local file copying at all. You just need to change the URL your existing repository is pointing to.

Assuming the usual parameters, your remote is probably named `origin` and you are probably in the `master` branch.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:your-username/new-repo-name
git push -u origin master
```

That will change where the `origin` remote points, and then push the master branch up to that new remote (server). The `-u` flag will set the `master` branch to automatically track this new URL, so in the future you can simply `git push` or `git pull` without having to specify a remote or a branch.

This will only push up the `master` branch, but you can repeat the commands as many times as needed to push up other branches.

```
git checkout some-branch
git push -u origin some-branch
```

This will completely move you to the new Git URL. It's also possible to set up a new remote alongside your old one. To do that, instead of changing the URL with `set-url`, you can just add another remote instead.

```
git remote add new-repo git@github.com:your-username/new-repo-name
git push -u origin master
```

Here again is the `-u` to set up automatic tracking. If you prefer not to change how the remote tracking is handled, simply omit the `-u`.